# xcodebuild - 'Code Sign error: Provisioning profile X can't be found' despite the fact it's on right place

Tags: ios, jenkins, code-signing, provisioning-profile, xcodebuild

Originally issue appears on `Jenkins` build but same I can reproduce with `xcodebuild`.

I've seen tons of similar questions on `SO`, however wasn't able to solve my issue - **provisioning profile xxx not found**.

```
xcodebuild -target xxx
```

[image]

```
sudo xcodebuild -target xxx PROVISIONING_PROFILE="688bbf8d-f84b-4061-9725-e2fd9ad7bedc"
```

[image]

Still not found, despite fact it's there:

[image]

What I tried to do:

- Restarted billion times `xCode`, `OS`
- Removed all provisioning profiles by doing `-rm -rf ...MobileDevices/provis../*`
- Re logged in, re download provisioning profiles in `xCode` accounts
- *Prayed*
- Opened provisioning profile file and checked `UUID` if it matches that number
- *Prayed again*
- `rm rf derived data`

Any of this worked out.

Comment: r u check the provisioning profile is invalid or not in developer account???

Comment: it's valid and it's there, but in that case I would expect different error?

Comment: It is building sucessfully with the same profile on another machine

Comment: ok you have to download the certificates from another machine thats machine are running successful.

Comment: if you download the certificates on machine 1 and same certificates download on machine 2 that will not work

Comment: Change your bundle identifier com.xxx.xxxx.

Comment: I can't change bundle identifier it was all set up before me, and it worked fine before, no update of xCode or something was done recently

Comment: Can you perform a xcodebuild -version on both machines and post the results please? And you can try not to run xcodebuild with sudo, that's unnecessary.